# Python: Passing complex (ffmpeg) arguments to Popen

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

This ffmpeg [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) invocation works :

```
command = ['ffmpeg', '-y',
           '-i', filename,
           '-filter_complex', 'showwavespic',
           '-colorkey', 'red',
           '-frames:v', '1',
           '-s', '800:30',
           '-vsync', '2',
           '/tmp/waveform.png']
process = sp.Popen( command, stdin=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
process.wait()
```

But I need to use ['compand, showwavespic'](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform) and this comma seems to be blocking the execution. [I also need to pass all sorts of strange characters](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform), like columns and, well, all that you can find in a CLI invocation.

How can I pass complex arguments?

Comment: colorkey is a filter, but it appears you're attempting to use it like an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just regular Python strings.  The string value is passed directly to FFmpeg, without any interpretation by the shell.

So when you see a command-line example like this,

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120" -frames:v 1 output.png
```

First, since the examples are passed to the shell, we have to "undo" the shell quoting.

```
ffmpeg
-i
input
-filter_complex
showwavespic=s=640x120
-frames:v
1
output.png
```

Then, we put it into a Python list.

```
command = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-i',
    'input',
    '-filter_complex',
    'showwavespic=s=640x120',
    '-frames:v',
    '1',
    'output.png',
]
```

As you can see, commas, spaces, and most other characters are not treated any differently, so there is nothing you need to do to quote them.  The main special characters are `\` and `'` which must be quoted, control characters which must be quoted as well, and the NUL character which cannot be used at all.

### More complicated example

In shell:

```
  ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -ac 2 -filter_complex:a '[0:a]aresample=8000,asplit[l][r]' \
    -map '[l]' -c:a pcm_s16le -f data /tmp/plot-waveform-ac1 \
    -map '[r]' -c:a pcm_s16le -f data /tmp/plot-waveform-ac2
```

In Python:

```
command = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-i', 'in.mp4',
    '-ac', '2',
    '-filter_complex:a', '[0:a]aresample=8000,asplit[l][r]',
    '-map', '[l]',
    '-c:a', 'pcm_s16le',
    '-f', 'data',
    '/tmp/plot-waveform-ac1',
    '-map', '[r]',
    '-c:a', 'pcm_s16le',
    '-f', 'data',
    '/tmp/plot-waveform-ac2',
]
```

As you can see, fairly straightforward.  Python is just a little more verbose, but more regular.

Comment: Nice answer. Also, I discovered [`shlex.split(command_line)`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) that does the break-up/construct for you :)

Comment: You seem to be pretty at ease with ffmpeg, can you please look at [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/1093326/how-can-i-use-both-filter-and-filter-complex-with-ffmpeg)?